# Distributions whose derivatives are Radon measures

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

It is not difficult to show that if $f\in L^{loc}_1(\mathbb{R})$ and its derivative $Df$ (as an element of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R})$)is a Radon measure in $\mathbb{R}$ with finite total variation, then $f\in L_\infty(\mathbb{R})$.  The question I have is in a sense a partial converse of the statement above.

> if $u\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is such that $Du$ is a Radon measure with total finite variation, does $u$ have a representation in $L^{loc}_1(\mathbb{R})$? that is, is there $f\in L^{loc}_1(\mathbb{R})$ such that
> $$u(\phi)=\int_\mathbb{R} \phi(t) f(t)\,dt,\qquad \phi\in\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$$

This may be a very simple question. I will appreciate any reference or solution to my question.

Comment: $u$ and the function given by $f(x)=\int_0^x Du(dt)$ have the same derivative, so they differ only by a constant.

Comment: @MaoWao: yikes! it was a very trivial question after all. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: $u'$ is a measure if and only if $u$ is of bounded variation. See for example my lecture notes on distributions here: https://math.ou.edu/~cremling/teaching/ln.html